# How to make menu link show for certain roles?

Tags: 8, navigation

I want to add "Login" and "Logout" to the same menu but only for the right role. In previous versions of Drupal, you would just add /user/login and /user/logout to a menu and it would only render one or the other based on if they actually were logged in or not.

However in D8, it looks like the Logout link shows regardless... is there a way to replicate this without creating multiple menus?

Comment: How does one log out if you hide the Log Out link? How does one login if you hide the Log In link?

Comment: Reverse your comment. You see Log out if you are logged in, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

In D8 this is a menu link class, which you can add to a menu in *.links.menu.yml:

*mymodule.links.menu.yml*

```
mymodule.logout:
  weight: 10
  menu_name: mymenu
  class: Drupal\user\Plugin\Menu\LoginLogoutMenuLink
```

This class shows *Log in* or *Log out* for user roles authenticated or not:

```
  public function getTitle() {
    if ($this->currentUser->isAuthenticated()) {
      return $this->t('Log out');
    }
    else {
      return $this->t('Log in');
    }
  }
```

and links it to the corresponding route:

```
  public function getRouteName() {
    if ($this->currentUser->isAuthenticated()) {
      return 'user.logout';
    }
    else {
      return 'user.login';
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hmm, so this is not handled automatically anymore?

Comment: You can add menu links in UI for /user/login and /user/logout, and it will show only one of them, because they have defined requirements for the user roles. You can't test this as admin though, because admin has access rights for both.